# QImage is null, but works in method call

Tags: c++, qt, hook, qimage

I'm trying to patch over a method call in a C++ application, but something isn't working correctly.

I've "successfully" replaced the method at runtime, but the img format/dimensions appear invalid & the resulting test.png is 0 bytes. However, the call to the original method at the end succeeds, as I can see the image become sharpened in the GUI.

```
QImage overrideBlitzSharpen(QImage &img, int radius)
{
    printf("Image %p: %d x %d @ %d (format %d) isNull: %s\n", &img, img.height(), img.width(), img.depth(), img.format(), img.isNull() ? "YES" : "NO");
    // example output: "Image 0x10c684be8: 0 x 0 @ 0 (format 0) isNull: YES"

    img.save("test.png", 0, 100);

    return (*originalBlitzSharpen)(img, radius);
}
```

Docs:
http://api.kde.org/kdesupport-api/kdesupport-apidocs/qimageblitz/html/classBlitz.html#a809992c7bd9627f058f60b0ab5f16d51

http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/4.8/qimage.html#isNull

Suggestions?

Comment: `return (*originalBlitzSharpen)(img, radius);` what are you trying to do here??

Comment: originalBlitzSharpen is a pointer to the original Blitz::sharpen() method that I've replaced with overrideBlitzSharpen, so I am forwarding the call to it after running my own code in order to pass back the correct results that the original called expected.

Comment: Aha, I asked because I rarely see people dereferencing function pointers before calling. It is not really needed.

Comment: Provide a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).